# odoo 9 - how to upload website?

Tags: windows-7, publish, web-hosting, odoo-9

I'm beginner in odoo 9 community edition. I'm finished creating apps(Employee Directory and CRM) and website. but i don't know how to deliver it to the client, or how to publish(upload) the wbsite created by odoo Website Builder.
what should I do. I'm using windows 7.(please explain to me in detail because I'm a beginner).

Thanksss a lot

Answer (score 0):

First. Its a web aplication, You need a server for this.

If you want use your computer, you must install an aplication for convert into a server, or just rent a server on web, install the aplication, configure the odoo instance redirect the domain to your server.